# Changing Background image using Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Having trouble using Create React App to change a background image I feed to my component through props. The docs say use the import syntax. This works but it would mean I have to hard code every background image to each component. Anyway to do this dynamically?

I noticed it won't let me use template literals on the import syntax as well. That would have fixed my issue I think.

```
import '../css/Avatar.css';
import photo from "../images/joe_exotic.jpg";


const Avatar = (props) => {

    return (
        <div 
        style={{backgroundImage: `url("${photo}")`}}
        className="avatar">
        </div>
    )
}

export default Avatar;
```

P.S: I checked out the other articles on StackOverflow regarding this and they didn't provide much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna avoid this way of doing, you can put your images in the `public` folder of your `React` app, et grab them like so :

```js
import '../css/Avatar.css';

const Avatar = (props) => {

    return (
        <div 
        style={{backgroundImage: `url("/joe_exotic.jpg")`}}
        className="avatar">
        </div>
    )
}

export default Avatar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works for you. good luck.

```
import '../css/Avatar.css';
import photo from "../images/joe_exotic.jpg";


 const Avatar = (props) => {

 return (
    <div 
    style={{backgroundImage:url(photo)}}
    className="avatar">
    </div>
) }
export default Avatar;
```